# Best method to use IDataReader as IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, ienumerable

I need to use *Linq* on any *IDataReader* implementations like this

```
var c = sqlDataReader.AsEnumerable().Count();
```

Example:

```
public abstract class Test
{
    public abstract SqlDataReader GetSqlDataReader();

    public void Foo()
    {
        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = GetSqlDataReader();
        IEnumerable<SqlDataReader> sqlEnumerable = sqlDataReader.AsEnumerable();
        var c = sqlEnumerable.Count();
        var s = sqlEnumerable.Sum();
        SqlDataReader first = sqlEnumerable.First();
        var t = first.GetSqlXml(10);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to write this.
Please, write your snippet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try, this:

```
public static class DataReaderExtension
{
    public class EnumeratorWrapper<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<bool> moveNext;
        private readonly Func<T> current;

        public EnumeratorWrapper(Func<bool> moveNext, Func<T> current)
        {
            this.moveNext = moveNext;
            this.current = current;
        }

        public EnumeratorWrapper<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return moveNext();
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get { return current(); }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> BuildEnumerable<T>(
            Func<bool> moveNext, Func<T> current)
    {
        var po = new EnumeratorWrapper<T>(moveNext, current);
        foreach (var s in po)
            yield return s;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this T source) where T : IDataReader
    {
        return BuildEnumerable(source.Read, () => source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use this:

```
MyDataReader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
```

But don't forget to have the linq statement execute before you close the DataReader.

using ToList() for instance

Answer (score 8):

You could create an extension method to do this **(see caveats below)**:

```
public static class DataReaderExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<Object[]> AsEnumerable(this System.Data.IDataReader source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        while (source.Read())
        {
            Object[] row = new Object[source.FieldCount];
            source.GetValues(row);
            yield return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Found here: http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/Consuming-a-DataReader-with-LINQ.aspx

---

As pointed out by @LukeH, note that as IDataReader only supports reading once, forwards, you'll only be able to query the enumerable once. (To get round this you could call ToList/ToArray, then query that).

Note that `SqlDataReader` already impliments IEnumerable so you won't need to do this in the example you've given.

Also, be aware that it's probably better to do any filtering/aggrigating on the server (via [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) for example)

Comment: Note that this won't allow them to do `Count` followed by `Sum` followd by `First` as in the example. (Although to do that they'd either need to re-query the db three times, or buffer the results somehow, both of which have potential pitfalls.)

Comment: @George Duckett
"Note that SqlDataReader already impliments IEnumerable so you won't need to do this in the example you've given.", yes it's true but I need IEnumerable<SqlDataReader> to use for example method "GetSqlXml"

Comment: "IEnumerable<Object[]> AsEnumerable", I need IEnumerable<SqlDataReader>

Comment: "you'll only be able to query the enumerable once" I know, but I can use "AsQueryable()" to do this.

Comment: @b2Lord, `IEnumerable<SqlDataReader>` doesn't make sense, as you only have one `SqlDataReader`, you're not enumerating over more than one `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: while (reader.Read()) { // In this loop it is possible to do somthing with "reader", so I also want to so somthing in any enumerabled item }

Comment: @b2Lord, but the enumerated item isn't the `SqlDataReader`, the `SqlDataReader` is the thing doing the enumerating. I'm sorry, i still don't follow your use-case.

Comment: I'm looking at the definitions for both [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx), neither of them actually implement `IEnumerable`...?

Answer (score 7):

Here are my two cents :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Enumerate<T>(this T reader) where T: IDataReader 
{ 
   using(reader) 
      while(reader.Read()) 
         yield return reader; 
} 

public void Test()
{
  var Res =
    from Dr in MyDataReader.Enumerate()
    select new {
      ID = (Guid)Dr["ID"],
      Description = Dr["Desc"] as string
    };
}
```

I felt the urge to post this, because it is very important to dispose a `DataReader` after use, and no answer mentioned it.

That's why my implementation has a `using` statement around the `while` loop. In this way, I can do "one hand" queries whithout worrying about the `DataReader` disposal.

Comment: It seems ok for your code but with more complex tables there could be an error which would stop the iteration and never dispose the reader. I had this issue and I created a "DisposableEnumerable" class so the using is done outside the Enumerate method and calls Dispose in case of problem.

Comment: +1 for making the suggestions about the `using` statement and the importance of closing the datareader.  In some environments, the DataReader could actually `Lock` a database, table, leaf, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You can just load the `DataReader` into a `DataTable` and then `Select()`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dataReader);
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select();        //DataRow[] Implements IEnumerable
```

or

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = dt.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel. It seems you have two accounts (http://stackoverflow.com/users/5547620/gabrielk, http://stackoverflow.com/users/5547612/gabriel-kniznik). If you wish to link them, please follow the steps at http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following but I like @Serge's suggestion better and it reminds be of what I believe I used to do but then forgot that IDataReader implements

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
var records = Enumerable
    .Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    .TakeWhile(i => reader.Read())
    .Select(i => reader as IDataRecord);
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I implemented the following generic solution as we don't like to depend on any third party dependencies or any complex solution.

**Simple and Fast `IDataReader` to `IEnumerable<T>` conversion using reflection + lambda expressions**

```
public IEnumerable<T> ConvertToEnumerable<T>(SqlDataReader dr) where T : class, new()
{
    List<string> lstColumns = Enumerable.Range(0, dr.FieldCount).Select(dr.GetName).ToList();
    List<PropertyInfo> lstProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => lstColumns.Contains(x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var entity = new T();
        lstProperties.Where(w => dr[w.Name] != System.DBNull.Value).ToList().ForEach(i => i.SetValue(entity, dr[i.Name], null));
        yield return entity;
    }
}
```

Usages

```
SqlDataReader dr;
...
var result = ConvertToEnumerable<Foo>(dr).FirstOrDefault();
Or
var result = ConvertToEnumerable<Foo>(dr).ToList();
```

Comment: It doesn't look very fast to run a `Where()` check into the properties and ToList() allocation on every single record