# return data in JSON format using restful web service

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am creating one web service which will fetch the data from database and return into json.but i amnot getting data.when i am running the code than in result i am getting ***"\"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader\""*** so what have tried now is below.can you help me where i have to correct the code.

***Iservice.cs***

```
namespace SearchService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]

        string Search(string keyword);


    }

}
```

***service1.cs***

```
namespace SearchService
{

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string Search(string keyword)
        {

            var json = "";
            var data = "";

            SqlConnection sql_Search;


            sql_Search = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=student_info;Integrated Security=True");
            sql_Search.Open();

            SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Student_ID,First_Name,Last_Name FROM record Where (First_Name Like '%" + keyword + "%')", sql_Search);


            SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader read = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {

                data = read.ToString();
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer JavaSerialzer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            json = JavaSerialzer.Serialize(data);
            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read.ToString()` will return the type of `read`, which is "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader".

You need to read the data as an object and serialize that. See [Convert rows from a data reader into typed results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202935/convert-rows-from-a-data-reader-into-typed-results) how to do that.

Easier even is to use an ORM to generate classes and read statically-typed objects from your database instead of building a query from a string (use parameterized queries) and then going to build an object from that reader.

But there's a *lot* more, fundamentally wrong with your code. You shouldn't be returning a JSON string wrapped in a (presumably) SOAP object from a WCF service, use the proper binding and just return the object itself, or use WebAPI.

Comment: Pretty big call to say someone should be using an ORM.

Comment: i am not getting the exact answer,so can you write that code.

Comment: @CodeCaster I would have to agree with CRice.  I would use the DataContractJsonSerializer to build JSON before I would ever recommend using an ORM

Comment: @Matthew that's nice, but I don't really see a compelling argument why.

Comment: @CodeCaster because the minute you run into a situation where your code is no longer performant, you've abstracted out the layer where you can do the most tuning.  You can potentially end up with a bad data model, should your application grow to the point that you need more than just container tables.  So to recommend ORM to a beginner would be MORE risky as they do not know the repercussions of using it or how to actually write a good data model.

Comment: @Matthew not following you nor agreeing with that. You can create an equally bad data model while reading with `SqlDataReader` as opposed to using an ORM. ORM does not necessarily mean "code first". It is (in terms of code) easier to get data out of a database with an ORM, hence it's very fitting for beginners. Beginners also don't often run into performance problems.

Comment: @CodeCaster Hm, perhaps you don't work on applications that scale very large.  Regardless, the value using an ORM is fast code creation and deployment.  If OP is a beginner, then ORM is a shortcut to get his application running.  For the same reason we learn Assembly and C in school long before we become masters at the high level languages we use today.  It would be like having a student dictate his book report to dragon voice recognition than actually learning to type himself

Answer (score 3):

Since you write it as;

```
read.ToString()
```

it will return the full name of that class obviously.

If you wanna read your column values, you can access them as `read[0]`, `read[1]` and `read[2]` etc. Or you can use `SqlDataReader`'s [`GetXXX` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods.aspx) as well.

By the way, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and reader as well.