# How to convert from DbDataReader to Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> in Entity Framework Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm calling a Stored Procedure in EF Core 2.0 in the following way.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> InvokeStoredProcedureAsync(string entityName)
{
    var storedProcedureName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "sp_{0}BulkSelect", entityName);
    dynamic temp;
    using (MyDbContext MyDbContext = new MyDbContext(_options))
    {
        MyDbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
        DbCommand cmd = MyDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           temp = reader.Cast<Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>>>();
        }
    }

    return await temp;
}
```

I need to convert from `DbDataReader` to `Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>>`.

But I'm getting this error when trying to expand the temp variable to see its value.

> Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.

Please refer the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from obvious async code issues, you can't materialize `DbDataReader` to class by simply calling `Cast`. If it was possible, there wouldn't be a need of micro ORMs like Dapper and similar.

EF Core currently does not expose a public way to do that. But if `TEntity` is a model entity class, you can simply use the [`FromSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions?view=efcore-2.0) method:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> InvokeStoredProcedureAsync(string entityName)
{
    var storedProcedureName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "sp_{0}BulkSelect", entityName);
    using (var db = new MyDbContext(_options))
    {
        var result = await db.Set<TEntity>().FromSql(storedProcedureName).ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Make sure the SP returns all expected columns by the `TEntity` mapping.

Comment: Its giving compilation error. "constraint are not allowed on non-generic declaration"

Comment: Error "'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()' is a method which is not valid in the given context"

Comment: Oops, sorry, of course this is part of some generic repository class I guess. And I forgot `()` after `Set<TEntity>`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

At the time your reader is called it is already closed as the `using`-block is complete. Also you need to read "row by row". Try the follwoing:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> InvokeStoredProcedureAsync(string entityName)
{
    var storedProcedureName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "sp_{0}BulkSelect", entityName);
    List<TEntity> temp = new List<TEntity>();
    using (MyDbContext MyDbContext = new MyDbContext(_options))
    {
        MyDbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
        DbCommand cmd = MyDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;

        using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
           while (await reader.ReadAsync())
               temp.Add(reader.Cast<TEntity>()); // ATTENTION: this does not work! (see below)
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

but I *think*  the cast used above does not do what you think. See the following thread for an example how to create an entity out of a reader: [Convert rows from a data reader into typed results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202935/convert-rows-from-a-data-reader-into-typed-results)

Comment: @viveknuna You need to do it inside the `using`-block - did you try that?

Comment: @viveknuna And that exception would be? I guess it's not `Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.` anymore?

Comment: Yes it’s different, I post post it in 15 mins

Comment: @viveknuna ...already found the problem, thanks to Prateek. Please see my update...

Answer (score 0):

In async method, no need to cast to task. That will happen by itself. reader object has single row. It should be read each row at a time.

```
var temp = new List<TEntity>();

  using (var reader = await  cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {
    while(await reader.ReadAsync()) {
        temp.add(CreateEntity(reader)) ;
     }
   }

return temp;

// this is tightly coupled to object. Generic methods can be made
//  to convert reader to object
public TEntity CreateEntity(SqlDataReader reader) => new TEntity()
    {
        Id = reader.GetInt32("id"),
        Col1 =  reader.GetString("col1"),
        Col2 =  reader.GetString("col2"),
        Col3 =  reader.GetString("col3")
    };
```

[async - msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming)

Comment: What I need to do here temp.add(//##add code to read perhaps each column ##) ;

Comment: updated the code. generic way to do reader to object can be done via link provided by @ChrFin  - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202935/convert-rows-from-a-data-reader-into-typed-results)

Comment: @Prateek Getting compilation error. "Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'TEntity' because it does not have the new() constraint"

Comment: TEntity - is it abstract class?  if yes  then you need to inherit this class and initialize the derived class...

Comment: Yes it is, but there are around 20 classes which are inheriting this abstract class. So according to your solution I will have to write multiple if else statements to create different different object, because different classes have different properties

Comment: well, if you are using procedures to get data you have to do this.
You can make generic method use reflection and map property of a class to to column names from procedures. This would only move the mapping logic and few line of repetitive code.

Comment: well @IvanStoev has added the answer.