# Populate multiple objects from JSON

Tags: c#, mysql, json, datatable, mysqldatareader

I have this code:

```
public class Customer
{
    Int32 id { get; set; } = 0;
    User user1 { get; set; } = null;
    User user2 { get; set; } = null;
}

/* ... */

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Costanti.connessione))
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand("
SELECT c1.*, u1.*, u2.*
FROM customers as c1
inner join utenti u1 on u1.customer_id = c1.id
inner join utenti u2 on u2.customer_id = c1.id
", conn);

    MySqlDataReader x = m.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Load(x);
    String json_string = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);

    List<Customer> lista = new List<Customer>();
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json_string, lista);
    conn.Close();
}
```

How could I map `c1.*` fields of select to a generic `Customer customer_1`, and then `u1.*` and `u2.*` into `customer_1`'s properties? `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject` doesn't let me do it.

The intermediate `json_string` looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "id_user":8,
      "name":"manuel",
      "id_user1":2,
      "name1":"michael"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "id_user":3,
      "name":"friedrich",
      "id_user1":6,
      "name1":"antony"
   }
]
```

And the result has to be a list composed by:

- `Customer(with id=1)`, with `User1(8,"manuel")` and `User2(2,"michael")`;
- `Customer(with id=2)`, with `User1(3,"friedrich")` and `User2(6,"antony")`.

Comment: What does the `json_string` look like?

Comment: It looks like that:

[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "id_user":8,
      "name":"manuel",
      "id_user1":2,
      "name1":"michael",
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "id_user":3,
      "name":"friedrich",
      "id_user1":6,
      "name1":"antony",
   },
]

And the result has to be a list composed by:

Customer(with id=1), with User1(8,"manuel") and User2(2,"michael");
Customer(with id=2), with User1(3,"friedrich") and User2(6,"antony");

Answer (score 1):

The main reason your call to `PopulateObject()` is not working is that your c# data model does not match the schema of your JSON.  If I use one of the tools from *[How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674)* to auto-generate a data model from your JSON, I get:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int id_user { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id_user1 { get; set; }
    public string name1 { get; set; }
}
```

This looks nothing like your `Customer` class.

The secondary reason that `PopulateObject()` fails is that Json.NET will only populate **`public`** members by default -- and yours are all private.

To fix this, I might suggest skipping the `DataTable` and `json_string` representations entirely, and building your list directly from the [`IDataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatareader?view=netframework-4.8) interface that [`MySqlDataReader`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm) implements:

```
var lista = x
    .SelectRows(r =>
        // Extract the row data by name into a flat object
        new
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(r["id"], NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
            id_user = Convert.ToInt32(r["id_user"], NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
            name = r["name"].ToString(),
            id_user1 = Convert.ToInt32(r["id_user1"], NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
            name1 = r["name1"].ToString(),
        })
    .Select(r =>
        // Convert the flat object to a `Customer`.
        new Customer
        {
            id = r.id,
            user1 = new User { Id = r.id_user, Name = r.name },
            user2 = new User { Id = r.id_user1, Name = r.name1 },
        })
        .ToList();
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    // Adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202973
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202935/convert-rows-from-a-data-reader-into-typed-results
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRows<T>(this IDataReader reader, Func<IDataRecord, T> select)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return select(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that your `Customer` data model now looks like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Int32 id { get; set; }
    public User user1 { get; set; }
    public User user2 { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You could also combine the `SelectRows` and `Select` calls into a single method; I separated them for clarity.  Skipping the `DataTable` and JSON representations should be simpler and more performant than your current approach.

Demo fiddle using a mockup data reader [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cq39va).