# IDataReader is closed when I try to return a tuple

Tags: c#, idatareader

I'm trying to return an HTTP Response that consists of an array of records I've selected from a database.  But I'm having trouble mapping my `IDataReader` to an `Enumerable`.  Here's the part of my code that's relevant:

```
namespace Web.Api.Controllers
{
    public static class Blah
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this IDataReader reader,
                                       Func<IDataReader, T> projection)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return projection(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Search")]
    public async Task<Tuple<int, IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>, int>> Search([FromBody]CustomerViewModel model)
    {
        var s = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionAlt");
        

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(s))
        {

            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Search @RegistrationDate=\"2020-07-09\"", connection))
            {
                using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var results = reader.Select<CustomerViewModel>(CustomerViewModel.Create);
                    return Tuple.Create(0, results, 29);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I send a POST request to `http://localhost:42432/api/Search`, the line `while (reader.Read())` gives the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.'
```

I put a breakpoint at `return Tuple.Create(0, results, 29);`, and when I inspect the `results` variable, it shows the results I expect.  But after I step out of that breakpoint, I get the error on the `while (reader.Read())`.

Can someone tell me how I can fix my problem?

---

I was following examples listed here:

[How can I easily convert DataReader to List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt)

[Convert rows from a data reader into typed results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202935/convert-rows-from-a-data-reader-into-typed-results)

---

EDIT - I am using dotnetcore

Comment: Please clarify the version of the skd you are using (,net framework or dot net core)?

Comment: @NicklausBrain I edited my question to say I'm using dot net core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the benefits of a Deferred Execution in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is the effect of [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example) when using `IEnumerable`, in this case, the `IEnumerable<T>` that's being returned from your `Select` method.

You're returning an `IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>` as part of the tuple, which at this point hasn't been executed. Then the connection & reader are being disposed through the usage of `using`.

When you subsequently try to iterate the `IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>` after the method has returned, the captured data reader has already been closed as part of the dispose.

When you inspect through the debugger, `Results` is a method that iterates over the enumerable, and at this point the data reader has not yet been disposed.

One option to prevent this would be to call `ToList` on your `results` before you return.

---

This is a similar concept to generators in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, that `IEnumerable` are processed lazily, on demand.
In your particular case, `Search` returns tuple value with the `IEnumerable` that is not yet read.
Therefore `reader` is being closed before the `IEnumerable` is populated.